# How to pass error from a processor to PutEmail processor in NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-nifi-registry

In the below image we can clearly see the error in the Conversion_Batching processor. How can this error be transmitted to PutEmail so that the email recipients can clearly understand the error.

[image]

Below is the **PutEmail** configuration:

[image]

But **${error}** is not getting the error from the previous processor and I am getting an empty mail with the subject correctly set as expected.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

NiFi currently does not have a feature where we can capture and pass exceptions/errors to the subsequent processors as attribute or flowfile content.

You can configure  `SiteToSiteBulletinReportingTask` which Publishes Bulletin events using the Site To Site protocol. This will give you information such as `bulletinsourceid, bulletinsourcename, bulletingroupname, bulletinmessage` etc and based on this you can then send out alert notification emails.

Another way is like in your process group `Conversion_Batching` introduce attribute `${error}` and set custom error messages wherever failure happens, and then you can use this attribute value in PutEmail processor, something like below,

[image: erro_handeling]

[image: error_attribute]